# HTMLcollection length is zero. Can't convert it to array. Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, htmlcollection

I replaced content on my html file with handlebars template. Now, I have this js code

```
function init() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    console.log("before click");
    console.log(elements);
    pullData();
    var arr = [].slice.call(elements);
    console.log(arr);

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log("before click");
        arr[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            console.log("after click");
            for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                arr[j].classList.remove('selected', 'no-hover');
            }
            var contentList = document.querySelectorAll('.show');
            console.log(contentList);
            for (var k = 0; k < contentList.length; k++) {
                contentList[k].classList.remove('show');
            }
            document.getElementById('right').style.display = 'block';
            var id = this.id;
            console.log(id);
            var targetElements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + id);
            console.log(targetElements);
            for (var x = 0; x < targetElements.length; x++) {
                targetElements[x].classList.add('show');
            }
            this.classList.add('selected', 'no-hover');
        });
    }
}
```

which was working fine before using handelbars template, as it was returning a nodelist, I was able to iterate over the elements and append a click to each element.

After using handlebars, my `elements` is a HTMLcollection, which I tried converting to array, but I am getting an empty array.

I have following questions. Is handlebars is causing this change?(returning HTMLcollection instead of node list) Or, am I just connecting two separate things?

Why am I getting an empty array?

Comment: the complete html or just the handlebars template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have solved this with a little bit of help.

The reason why I was getting an empty array was because my JS code was trying to convert the HTMLcollection before handlebars was done building the template.

I checked this by displaying the length of the HTMLcollection that was coming out as zero.

All, I had to do to fix this was to make sure that I convert the collection to an array after the handlebars template was done with its process.